# Limited Linux admin account just to provide VM disk drive extension

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

Title of the question kind of sums it up.  I am deploying a network appliance as a VM based on Debian 9 but want to give the user the ability to add additional disk space if needed, however I do not want them to have full system access on the command line.  How can I create an account that's limited to only performing fdisk type activities?  Also I want to limit their file system access so they cannot browse the disk.

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot actually keep a user out as soon as you give them the image or appliance.

Comment: Agreed but that's why we have licenses.  I just don't want them accidentally messing anything else up.

Answer (score 1):

You should just automate the task of resizing the virtual hard drive and filesystem instead.

For instance, cloud-init can be set up to automatically [grow the partitions](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#grow-partitions) (and filesystems) of virtual machine instances, and is already set to do so on VM instances from major cloud providers such as Amazon AWS and Google Cloud. You can use cloud-init yourself to automate this task. In this case, the end user would resize the virtual disk in their hypervisor, then reboot the instance, and cloud-init would automatically do all of the necessary steps.

The example from the documentation:

```
#cloud-config
#
# growpart entry is a dict, if it is not present at all
# in config, then the default is used ({'mode': 'auto', 'devices': ['/']})
#
#  mode:
#    values:
#     * auto: use any option possible (any available)
#             if none are available, do not warn, but debug.
#     * growpart: use growpart to grow partitions
#             if growpart is not available, this is an error.
#     * off, false
#
# devices:
#   a list of things to resize.
#   items can be filesystem paths or devices (in /dev)
#   examples:
#     devices: [/, /dev/vdb1]
#
# ignore_growroot_disabled:
#   a boolean, default is false.
#   if the file /etc/growroot-disabled exists, then cloud-init will not grow
#   the root partition.  This is to allow a single file to disable both
#   cloud-initramfs-growroot and cloud-init's growroot support.
#
#   true indicates that /etc/growroot-disabled should be ignored
#
growpart:
  mode: auto
  devices: ['/']
  ignore_growroot_disabled: false
```

Comment: My solution is not running in AWS, Google, etc.  Do you have an example of how to setup cloud-init for the specific use-case I'm asking about?  Seems like an interesting solution but it's the first I've heard of it.

Comment: @user987 Click the link.

Comment: It doesn't help nor do links help on this site.  You're proposing an totally new solution outside of what I was expecting and just say RTFM.  Have you used cloud-init yourself?

Comment: @user987 Yes, and it is so trivial, but since you asked, here is a copy of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sudoers file (`/etc/sudoers`, but best to edit with the `visudo` tool) to allow a group of users the usage of sudo(8) limited to a specific command. You can even add the arguments that are allowed so users can't call fdisk on an unrelated disk.

The entry in the file might look something like this:

`%yourgroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/fdisk /dev/sdb`

`man sudoers` has more information about the command syntax and possible options.